# Webpack 4 dynamic import not producing separate chunk

Tags: webpack, dynamic-import

I'm trying to async import lodash as an example, but it gets included in the main chunk instead

`Version: webpack 4.23.1`

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: 'sourcemap',
  entry: {
    "entry1": "./src/entry1.ts"
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "[name].js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].js",
  },
  // ...
}
```

I made a simple code just to reproduce the issue

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
  console.log('DOMContentLoaded')
  // lodash should be made into a separate chunk
  // but it gets included in the entry1 chunk
  const _ = await import('lodash')
  console.log('loaded test chunk')
  console.log(_.concat)
})
```

The complete repo is linked below
https://github.com/unlocomqx/webpack4-async-chunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake

I changed `"module": "esnext",` in tsconfig and it worked!